# How to get streamline colour to reflect flow speed

Tags: streamplot

Sorry I just can't fathom how to get a wide range of colours on a white background to represent speed and the color legend bar output.  M. seems so complicated about this. I have spent hours trying.
On sleeping on it, the other and conventional way might be to incrementally trace the stream function by spacing the streamlines in y as u (or in x as v) or normally as the norm. In reality the shear flow is actually long numerical integrations of inductions of vortex sheets so another integration in y from y=0 to create the streamfunction directly would add alot to the already very large computing time

This is a sample 2D shearing flow  1 + .4 y around a source at the origin. Of course there are very large speeds very close to the origin but I would like the speed variation in the  shear to show up . What further code do I need to show the speeds quantitively, or to control their streamline spacing to give constant flux increments.

```
    StreamPlot[{1 + .4 y + .2*x/(x*x + y*y), .2 y/(x*x + y*y)}, {x, -1,  3}, {y, -1, 1},
      Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

Comment: Does this take you any further (change scaling as you see fit)? `, StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - Norm[{#1, #2}]] &)
, StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend["Rainbow"], After]`.

Comment: @Syed. Thanks alot. I modified a bit but  how do I adjust the top speed of the scale? like the top speed of the approaching shear  ranges from .6 to 1.4  whereas color coded as a bit above 0 to a bit below 1                                                                              StreamPlot[{1 + .4 y + .2*x/(x*x + y*y), .2 y/(x*x + y*y)}, {x, -4, 
  3}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Norm[{#1, #2}]] &), 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend["Rainbow"], Below]]

Comment: `StreamPlot[{1 + .4 y + .2*x/(x^2 + y^2), .2 y/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -4, 
  3}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Norm[{#1, #2}], {0.6, 1.4}]] &), 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.6, 1.4}}], Below]]`  ?

Comment: @syed good. How do I control the number of streamlines shown?

Comment: Check the `StreamPoints` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPoints.html).

Comment: Last comment: With the source turned off, Daniel Huber's answer shows uniform colored streamlines that you are looking for. I suggest you use that and adjust scaling as required.

Comment: @syed still not confident in it. Here with source turned off, colour should just be uniform with xS                                                                                                StreamPlot[{1 + .4 y + 0*x/(x^2 + y^2), 0* y/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -2
  , 2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Norm[{#1, #2}], {0.6, 1.4}]] &), ImageSize -> 500, 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True, StreamPoints -> 40, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.6, 1.4}}], Below]]

Comment: @syed Huber's just gives red everywhere then. Not right, should be changing to green at boom

Answer (score 4):

Building on the comment from Seyd:

From the help you get that the 5th argument of StreamColorFunction is the norm of the velocity. You can use this to color the arrows.

```
StreamPlot[{1 + .4  y + .2*x/(x*x + y*y), .2  y/(x*x + y*y)}, {x, -1, 
  3}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][400  #5] &), 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1.5}}, 4], After]]
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: But the speed at y=1 at large x should be 1.4 but it is showing as 1.

Comment: "BarLegend" without any range gives a range from 0..1. You can specify a range by e.g.: `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1.5}}, 4]`  I change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Still all red and no shear when source turned off.                                          
  StreamPlot[{1 + .4 y + 0*x/(x*x + y*y), 0* y/(x*x + y*y)}, {x, -1, 
  3}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][400 #5] &), 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1.5}}, 4], After]]

Comment: Your function has syntax errors. It should read: `{1 + 0.4   y + 0.2*x/(x*x + y*y), 0.2   y/(x*x + y*y)}`

Comment: That collapses to what I had and is still showing all red for {1+.4*y ,0} for your streamColorFunction and some variation but changing with x for Syed's.

Comment: I just checked if my code is gives the above picture . Copy it and you should be fine. If not, there may be a version problem. I have version 14.0

Comment: Thanks but what does your code and version produce when the source .2 is made 0, so there should be .6 to 2.4  at all  X? In my version 9 it is just all red arrows.

Comment: You have to change StreamColorFunction to `StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][ #5] &)`